# Strange error when try to select single row from db

Tags: database, go, select

I have query:

```
query := "select id from atable where id1=$1 and id2=$2"
```

and now i need to select single record so i try to use

```
id1 := "1" 
id2 := "2"
rows, err := db.QueryRow(query, id1, id2)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("SQL select error: ")
        log.Println(err)
    }
```

and i get error

```
assignment mismatch: 2 variables but 1 values(undefined)
```

in string

```
rows, err := db.QueryRow(query, id1, id2)
```

it very strange, i dont have ny problem with just `db.Query(query)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QueryRow` only returns `*Row`
https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.QueryRow

`rows, err := db.QueryRow(query, id1, id2)`

should be:

`rows := db.QueryRow(query, id1, id2)`